# How to install service in OS X

Tags: install4j

I add "Install a service" and "Start a service" install4j

This service is executed well in windows.

but This service is not inatalled in OS X.

This is installation.log

=================================================================

[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.services.InstallServiceAction [ID 58]: Execute action not successful after 9 ms

[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.services.StartServiceAction [ID 59]: Execute action not successful after 4 ms

===================================================================

I execute install4j sample program

"C:\ProgramFiles\install4j5\samples\hello\hello.install4j" for service in OS X.

"Hello World Suite Installer.app" is installed in my OS X.

this sample "Hello World Suite Installer.app"  is inclued service.

There are Error....in service..

Please let me know what problem is.

Comment: Most likely, the service launcher has not been included in the Mac OS X installer

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes:

1. You are using *buggy* version of install4j. There was a bugfix in version [5.1.15 (see release notes)](https://www.ej-technologies.com/download/install4j/changelog.html#5.1.15).
2. The service launcher has not been included in the Mac OS X installer. (as mentioned Ingo Kagel in comment above).